# Is it safe to replace a 4400mAh laptop battery with a 8800mAh battery?

Tags: laptop, battery

I have an Acer Aspire 5536G. My battery is having problems so I am thinking of replacing it. I have searched online through many sites and I found some good deals. However, currently my laptop has a 4400mAh lithium ion battery so I was thinking of replacing it with 8800mAh 12-cell battery that lasts more hours than 4400mAh without power plug.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, its safe as long as its output voltage & current values are same. Output voltage has more importance.
And, the biggest thing: If a battery is available directly for Acer Aspire 5536G, its 100% safe rated by manufacturer.

Comment: With modern laptops (at least the last 15 years) it is not necessary to match voltages. It is very common for manufacturers to offer several different battery packs for a single laptop model. These will differ in the number of cells in the pack. In some cases, the pack with more cells will have a higher terminal voltage. THe laptops cope just fine, due to the use of DC to DC converter circuits (not just regulators). These accept a very wide range of input voltages. And you've never had to match max current either, not that that is a common laptop battery spec.

Answer (score 9):

The mAh value is a measurement of a battery's capacity calculated from the average number of amps discharged multiplied by the number of hours it took to fully discharge.  It represents the amount of current the battery could theoretically discharge in one hour.  For example, a battery that can discharge 500 mA for four hours has a capacity of 2000 mAh.

The battery will only supply as much amperage as the device requires, so a higher mAh rating is not a problem (and indicates longer battery life).  What matters here is that the voltage of the battery matches that of the computer.

Comment: Actually, it indicates capacity, not maximum current. Also, many battery technologies can show more capacity with a lower load than a higher one.

Answer (score 4):

This is much like asking "is it safe to replace a car's gas tank with a larger one?" Well, the larger gas tank will take more space, will weigh more, and will take longer to fill. So will the larger laptop battery.

But in terms of safety, the answer in both cases in an unequivocal "yes". You see, the mAh rating of a battery is really just a convenient way of expressing how many electrons the battery can push through a load until its charge is depleted. The larger-capacity battery will *in no way* damage the laptop.

n.b.: In addition to running the laptop for longer (maybe more than twice as long, because you'll be draining it at a slower rate relative to its capacity), it will take a roughly proportionally longer time to charge from "empty" (i.e. laptop is forced to power off) to fully charged.